# QGIS create layer with the points of the beginnings and ends of a polylines layer (without duplicate points)

Tags: qgis, postgis, point, line

In QGIS, i would like to create a new layer containing the beginning and end points of a polylines layer, but without the duplicate points that would result of adjacent polylines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my layers loaded in QGIS Map Canvas are loaded from postgis, i used the st_endpoint() and st_startpoint() Postgis functions to find the start and end point of each polyline and i made a union of both SQL to remove the duplicates. It works perfect loading the SQL with the DB Manager to QGIS Map Canvas. I added a (row_number() OVER () AS id) sentence to create a unique identifier that the DB Manager needed. The query would be:

SELECT  (row_number() OVER () AS id, A1."GEOMETRY" FROM (SELECT DISTINCT st_endpoint(YOUR_TABLE."GEOMETRY") AS "GEOMETRY" FROM YOUR_TABLE) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT st_startpoint(YOUR_TABLE."GEOMETRY") AS "GEOMETRY" FROM YOUR_TABLE)) AS A1;

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

create 4 point from 2 line:

> SELECT (row_number() OVER () )AS id, A1.gid as orginalgid, p as
>   startorend ,A1.geom FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT gid, 'ep' as p ,
>   st_endpoint(st_linemerge(tmpsel.geom)) AS geom FROM tmpsel) UNION
>   (SELECT DISTINCT gid, 'sp' as p,
>   st_startpoint(st_linemerge(tmpsel.geom)) AS geom FROM tmpsel)) AS A1;

Comment: Is there a simple way to execute these queries (maybe in the Python console?) on geojson or shapefiles not in a PostGIS database?